# border-radius property with input text tag not working properly in Chrome browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to use border-radius property with input text tag to get rounded corner. I am able to achieve rounded corner in all the browsers i.e. Firefox,IE and in Chrome but I see one problem in Chrome. In chrome I am able to see one rectangular box along with the rounded textbox. Can anyone please tell me what is the reason for this and how can I remove the rectangular box? my Chrome version is 31.0.1650.63m

The html code that I am using to test is given below-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style> 
    input
    {
    border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
    padding:10px 40px; 
    background:#dddddd;
    width:200px;
    border-radius:25px;
   }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>

   <input type="text"></input>

   </body>
   </html>
```

[image: Firefox]
[image: chrome]
[image: ie10]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `outline: 0;` to the input

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BWJmg/) for an example

Comment: You may then want to add some styles to `input:focus` to let the user know they have clicked on the input

Answer (score 3):

Try using `appearance` to hide the default styling:

```
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance:    none;
   appearance:         none;
```

Also `outline: none;` on the focus state to hide the blue box.

Answer (score 2):

Like the other users say the problem here is specific with the state `:focus` and `outline` property. You can remove the square setting it to `0`:

```
input:focus {
  outline:none;
}
```

But in order to keep the plus accesibility `outline` provide for users (using <kbd>Tab</kbd>) you may want to keep some effect like this faked with `box-shadow`:

```
input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px green;
}
```

Check this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7EZCg/)**